# Run FitNesse Tests from Eclipse

Tags: java, junit, fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

How can I run FitNesse tests from Eclipse IDE? 
I was trying to use jUnit Runner. I want to know the steps to implement the runner class and execute FitNesse tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the [unit test from the project](https://github.com/unclebob/fitnesse/blob/master/test/fitnesse/junit/FitNesseRunnerTest.java) help? The `Suite` annotation defines which tests to run.

```
@RunWith(FitNesseRunner.class)
@FitNesseRunner.Suite("FitNesse.SuiteAcceptanceTests.SuiteSlimTests.TestScriptTable")
@FitNesseRunner.FitnesseDir(".")
@FitNesseRunner.OutputDir("./build/fitnesse-results")
public class FitNesseRunnerTest {
}
```

Comment: Where am I suppose to find my test pages in FitNesseRoot directory? My FitNesseRunnerTest executed successfully. It created  FitNesse.SuiteAcceptanceTests.SuiteSlimTests.TestScriptTable.html in OutputDir. But I don't see my tests being executed. I just want to run my test page. I tried complete url of the page but it throws an error "No page found"

Comment: Have you tried the complete URL of your page, or did you strip 'http://localhost:<port>/' prefix? The latter is what should have worked. So if http://localhost/MySuite.MyTest is the url you enter `Suite("MySuite.MyTest")`

Comment: MySuite.MyTest was the catch. Thanks for the suggestion. I see an HTML page is being generated in OutputDir, after running the FitNesseRunnerTest. Is that it? Also, can I use FitNesseRunner in continuous integration tools such as Jenkins to run my FitNesse tests.

Comment: For each test executed a HTML page will be generated, and a single overview page.

Comment: I use this to run my tests on build servers such as Jenkins. I create a job that runs a unit test (using maven failsafe plugin), see https://github.com/fhoeben/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures/wiki#2-run-on-build-server and https://github.com/fhoeben/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures/blob/master/pom.xml and

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's really helpful. Also, how can you add more test cases to the FitNesse suite? So after creating the job and running the tests on the build servers, is it possible to go to the wiki web page (test page) and add some more tests cases to the wiki page, on the build server?

Comment: To add more tests, or change existing ones, I just change the wiki pages (below/inside the suite the build server runs) on my local machine, commit the changes and the build server picks these changes up automatically (it polls version management, detects the changes I made, updates its workspace and runs the job again).